# else result not be displayed in while loop - javascript

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I have a while loop where there's an if, else if, and else condition. When I run the loop, the else condition at the very end is never displayed and I'm trying to figure out why it is. Here's the code:

```
var loopEnd = 1;
while (loopEnd != 2) {
  var conversion = prompt("Do you want to convert miles to km, or km to miles?");
  if (conversion == "miles to km") {

    var miles = 0;
    var miles = prompt("How many miles do you want to convert?");
    var kilometers = 1.61 * miles;
    while (miles != 0) {
        alert("The number of kilometers for " + miles + " miles is " + kilometers + " kilometers.");
        var miles = prompt("How many miles do you want to convert?");
        var kilometers = 1.61 * miles;
                   }
    var promptEnd = prompt("Do you want to convert anything else?");
    if (promptEnd == "no") {
        var loopEnd = 2;
        } else {
        alert("Okay, let's convert something else!");
        }

    } else if (conversion == "km to miles") {

    var kilometers = 0;
    var kilometers = prompt("How many kilometers do you want to convert?");
    var miles = 0.62 * kilometers;
    while (kilometers != 0) {
      alert("The number of miles for " + kilometers + " kilometers " + miles + " miles.");
      var kilometers = prompt("How many kilometers do you want to convert?");
      var miles = 1.61 * kilometers;
    }
    var promptEnd = prompt("Do you want to convert anything else?");
    if (promptEnd == "no") {
      var loopEnd = 2;

 // } else {

    alert("Sorry, I didn't quite catch that.");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please spot in the code which else you mean?

Comment: please try to format your code more neatly, indenting blocks and braces together. It is probably a mis-placed `}` but hard to spot as it is.

Comment: sure. it's the else that's commented out towards the end. and yeah, i'll try to format it more neatly really quickly.

Comment: I ran the code, and it worked for me, I can't find the problem.

Comment: the problem was that instead of the code running the else statement at the very bottom, it was running a different else statement because i messed up the placement of the brackets. jesse warren provided the correct solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are refering to the else with the alert in it then you need to reformat your code. Here try this

```
var loopEnd = 1;
while (loopEnd != 2) {
    var conversion = prompt("Do you want to convert miles to km, or km to miles?");
    if (conversion == "miles to km") {

    var miles = 0;
    var miles = prompt("How many miles do you want to convert?");
    var kilometers = 1.61 * miles;
    while (miles != 0) {
        alert("The number of kilometers for " + miles + " miles is " + kilometers + " kilometers.");
        var miles = prompt("How many miles do you want to convert?");
        var kilometers = 1.61 * miles;
    }
    var promptEnd = prompt("Do you want to convert anything else?");
    if (promptEnd == "no") {
        var loopEnd = 2;
    } else {
        alert("Okay, let's convert something else!");
    }


} else if (conversion == "km to miles") {

    var kilometers = 0;
    var kilometers = prompt("How many kilometers do you want to convert?");
    var miles = 0.62 * kilometers;
    while (kilometers != 0) {
        alert("The number of miles for " + kilometers + " kilometers " + miles + " miles.");
        var kilometers = prompt("How many kilometers do you want to convert?");
        var miles = 1.61 * kilometers;
    }
    var promptEnd = prompt("Do you want to convert anything else?");
    if (promptEnd == "no") {
        var loopEnd = 2;
    }
}
else {
    alert("Sorry, I didn't quite catch that.");
}
}
```

Also Rhumborl is right you need to clean up your code and give it proper spacing.

Comment: thanks for the help! i'm pretty new to this so i'll try my best to pick up on proper formatting and spacing.